# Keyword not supported 'provider' error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, sql-server-2000, connection-string

c#.Net 3.5 with a SQL Server 2000 backend, I have a connection string in my app.config file that looks like this

```
<add name="MFG_ConnectionString" 
  connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MFG;Persist Security Info=True;Password=kb1234;User ID=kb;Initial Catalog=MFG" 
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

This connection string was built with the data source configuration wizard.  Creating a dataset with this and dragging the DataSource element to create a DataGridView populates and successfully allows all CRUD operations.

However, I'm not looking to make changes to this through a databound form.  I'm looking to do this behind the scenes in code.  Since this is an older version of SQL Server I'm assuming I must use OleDbConnection and other OleDb objects to get the job done.  When I try to execute the following:

```
OleDbConnection visualConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MFG_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

I get an exception: "Keyword not supported 'provider'.
Yet if I take out provider I'm told that I must supply one.  Not sure why this works through the dataset on the form yet I cannot create my own connection object... any thoughts?

*EDIT* It should be noted that when I originally created the connection to this database, it told me that the database I was trying to connect to did NOT support SqlConnection and that I must choose another (my choice being OleDb at that time).  It is odd to me that this connection works behind the scenes as SqlConnection without provider in the connection string but the dataset then breaks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlConnection` works fine with SQL 2000. You can get a connectionstring sample [here](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server)

Comment: Changing to SqlConnection gives me the same error, so I go in and take out the Provider part of the string and it works fine.  Now I'm trying to figure out why.  If I change the connection string to exclude provider, the dataset ceases to function propertly.  Is the only solution to have two connection strings, one for the dataset and the other for the manual connection?

Comment: When you switched to SqlConnection, your connection string should look like one of the ones on the site. My personal favorite is "Server=SOMESERVERNAME;Database=SOMEDATABASENAME;User ID=SOMEUSERID;Password=SOMEPASSWORD;" - With that, you should have no trouble connecting, regardless of whether you're retrieving a DataSet, reader, executing commands, or using any ORM.

Comment: Which is what I switched to, and it works in code behind just fine.  However all of the controls on forms linked to the dataset using this connection cease to function because it cannot interpret the connection string anymore.  For some reason without provider in the connection string I loose the capability of dataset binding on my forms

Comment: How are you binding your form controls? If you've got a connection in your markup, like a OleDbDataSource object, then that would need to change to a SqlDataSource as well. However, IMO you really should never do that anyway, since it breaks the idea of keeping your client and your data separate.

Comment: The IDE has handled all of that for me, I dragged the table onto the form to create a datagridview and customized output from there.  One of the tables must be used behind the scenes to make other decisions but if It will not allow me to change it to sqlconnection.  Says it's not supported for this version though I'm beginning to think it's referring to this databinding functionality is not supported...

Comment: I just noticed this looks like it's WinForms, I was thinking of ASP.NET. But the principle's the same. If you're using designer-generated code, then you can always edit the designer file. Try looking in the .designer file and look for your grid control. I'd bet you'll find code related to the connection, and you can manipulate it as needed - it's probably still using your OleDb connection instead of the Sql connection. Or, I'd still recommend not binding through the designer, and instead binding manually through code, then your control would have no tie whatsoever to your database.